# Posting voice (mp3 file) on facebook profile

Tags: facebook, file-upload, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-php-sdk

Can anyone please let me know how to post voice update on facebook, on a user's wall, using the php/js - sdk and Graph API.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would publish a post to the user's feed containing a link to the mp3. The mp3 needs to be hosted on the internet somewhere.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/